# Why when I create a page it displays in navigation menu on wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have multiple pages on my wordpress website, I am creating a custom wordpress theme.
The problem is, when I create a page it automaticly adds to my menu (navigation bar) at the top of the page.

I want to create a page, then make a link to that page, but instead when a page is created, it add's to top of the navigation.

How can I solve this problem?

P.S I did not toggle "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu"